# Comparing two region in Gemfire

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I have two huge regions REGION-A and REGION-B (200 Million rows in each region)
Now I am checking to see if both the region are identical or not.

Also, i want to return the mismatch. Is there any way in Gemfire to achieve this?

Comment: I would question the need to have two regions with almost the same content. Can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve? I suspect you can use CacheWriters, CacheListeners to do processing that eliminates  the need to have two regions.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to achieve this in GemFire out of the box.

You'll need to implement the logic by yourself iterating through the keys and do the value comparison manually, either inside a custom function, or from client side.

Another approach, maybe less impacting in terms of performance, would be to take a [snapshot](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/managing/cache_snapshots/chapter_overview.html) of both regions and compare the contents offline.

Hope this helps.
Cheers.